# Update script with powershell, check specific date on website before download?

Tags: html, powershell

I hope someone got a little help or ideas how to realize an update tool using powershell.

General idea:
Before a zipped file will be downloaded, it must check and compare two dates for differences (in days).
One date of an .exe file, the other date on a website.

The routine so far for me was to download the file first (regardless of any date) and then a checkup and comparison of two dates from two files (.exe files) happens. Depending on the dates, I continue some replacing and deleting.

Since the download process (around 30mb) always occurs, id like to have some kind of comparison first (if possible), to avoid the download process every time, when not needed.

What I got working so far for the comparison of two .exe file is:

```powershell
$DaysSinceMod = (((Get-ItemProperty -Path $betaFile).LastWriteTime)-(Get-ItemProperty -Path $currentFile).LastWriteTime).Days
        if ([int]$DaysSinceMod -gt 0){
          DO STUFF (replacing older .exe File)
        }
```

Now id like to change it as it needs to checkup the website for the date first. My problem is, I dont know how to get it done in powershell smoothly. An idea of mine was to somehow download the website code first, which is as followed (had to change some names):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /AA/beta</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /AA/beta</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/AA/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File.zip">File.zip</a></td><td align="right">2021-04-20 15:42  </td><td align="right"> 25M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File2.zip">File2.zip</a></td><td align="right">2021-04-20 15:42  </td><td align="right"> 37M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File3.zip">File3.zip</a></td><td align="right">2021-04-20 15:42  </td><td align="right"> 24M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File4.zip">File4.zip</a></td><td align="right">2016-02-03 14:39  </td><td align="right">862 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File5.zip">File5.zip</a></td><td align="right">2016-02-03 14:39  </td><td align="right">103K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="disclaimer_beta_version.txt">disclaimer_beta_version.txt</a></td><td align="right">2014-03-18 09:31  </td><td align="right">642 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="FILE6.zip">FILE6.zip</a></td><td align="right">2021-04-20 15:42  </td><td align="right"> 38M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="File7.zip">File7.zip</a></td><td align="right">2021-04-20 15:42  </td><td align="right"> 37M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache Server at AAA.BBB.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

My goal would be to reach the date of FILE6, and if the date is newer than the existing file, a download process would occur.

I would be really happy, if someone could help out a little bit, thanks.

If any questions or further informations are needed, please let me know.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, you'd first have to get the html from the site (e.g. using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)).

And after that, parse the html. I strongly recommend using a dedicated library for that (e.g. [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)), but for this simple case I think regex will suffice.

Here's one simple suggestion:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest "https://your-url").RawContent -match 'FILE6.+>(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)'
$date = [datetime]$Matches[1]
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it.

Comment: Wow, what a wonderful, elegant solution :) Thank you very much